# Numpy isn't working in script

Tags: python, numpy

Using NumPy for python version 3.6, just installed it via `pip`. For simple scripts I keep getting an odd error that I can't understand

Example script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((2,2))
print(a)
```

Output being when run:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in 
>   File "/Users/Zhiang/Projects/LearningPython/Test.py", line 4, in
>    a = np.zeros((2,2))  # Create an array of all zeros
>   AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'zeros'

I am still new to using python and have no idea what to do. I have tried reinstalling NumPy.Even going as far as reinstalling `pip` for python 3.6. Anyone know what to do ?

Comment: If you have ipython installed, run it in ipython, type `np??` and see what it says. Also, make certain there's nothing called numpy.py in your project.

Comment: ok. In your terminal just type python to start a terminal session. `import numpy` then type `numpy.__version__`  Do you see the right version?

Comment: @GregJennings ok when i do that, it gives me this error:::                        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: bad magic number in 'numpy': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'

Comment: @GregJennings I just typed in `import numpy` to a terminal session, also I did have a file with a name numpy.py which was deleted

Comment: Ok. Were you using a different python version previously, then upgraded? Try to delete any pyc files and and see if it will go again. OR, (much easier and recommended for beginner), just download anaconda  https://www.continuum.io/downloads   It does a good job of handling all of the dependencies associated with the python mathematical libraries for you. It could also be that python 3.6, being very new, isn't yet supported by  your numpy. Make sure to get the right version off pypi to match your python. Or again, just get anaconda.

Comment: @GregJennings holy crap I just deleted the pyc files, and a test script works now ! Just for future reference why cant you have pyc files in the same directory that you are running your scripts in ?

Comment: Great to hear. I added an answer quickly below based on this exchange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133399/discussion-between-greg-jennings-and-user3802685).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments - Issue solved by deleting the pyc files.

Python checks to see if the .pyc file's internal timestamp matches the corresponding .py file, and if it does, it loads the .pyc. This can be an issue if you update and you're still using the previously compiled .pyc.